# Select for multiple relation values

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I've been trying for hours to solve this issue.

I've got 3 relations.

User, Knowledge, Skill and Expertise.

I need to find by Skill's ID Users who knows it. At the same time I want to use multiple Skills.

I want to be able to sort it by Expertise in specific skill, is that possible ? It doesn't matter if the SQL will be complex. I just want it in 1 command.

**User relation:**
[image: User relation]

**Knowledge relation:**
[image: Knowledge relation]

**Skill relation:**
[image: Skill relation]

**Expertise relation:**
[image: Expertise relation]

**So goal is**:

- Be able to find Users by multiple Skill's IDs
- Be able to sort Users by Expertise in specific Skill

**In Doctrine:**
[image: In Doctrine]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find Users by multiple Skill's IDs

```
select u.*
from User u
inner join Knowledge k on k.user_id = u.id
inner join Skill s on k.skill_id = s.id
where s.id in (:ids)
group by u.id, u.name
having count(s.id) = (select count(*) FROM skill where id in (:ids))
```

Sort Users by Expertise in specific Skill

```
select u.id, u.name, e.name
from User u
inner join Knowledge k on k.user_id = u.id
inner join Skill s on k.skill_id = s.id
inner join Expertise e k.expertise_id = e.id
where s.name = 'My Skill'
order by e.name
```

Comment: There is a problem with "in", because when user has 1 skill and not the 2nd one, it will still return the user.

Comment: Only users with skills in skill ids (:ids) will be returned by this query

Comment: But i need to get only users, who has all of mentioned skills

Comment: Oh ok, I did not understand that.

I updated my answer, did it match your need ?

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I've just updated it with doctrine code, that looks promising, just trying to find some error that cause 'Expected Literar, got 'SELECT'